# Creating a visualization of memory usage in Java

Tags: java, memory, user-interface

Is there a way to determine/calculate the values of all of the memory usages that a Java program is using during runtime, and to continue to calculate them every so often? I am trying to create a visual representation of the total memory being used in a program and display it on some sort of chart or line graph, and continue to update the graph periodically for a project I am currently working on.

I've seen other questions that ask to view the memory and people have suggested VisualVM, but I do not just want to see the memory being used, but actually use the values of the memory used. (Does VisualVM do that?)

As a side question, is it possible to see how much memory a particular thread in the code is using, or can I only view the overall usage?

Comment: What do you mean, "how much memory a particular thread in the code is using"?  Objects don't necessarily belong to just one thread.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/07/compute-java-object-memory-footprint-at.html

Comment: @LouisWasserman Well thats what Im curious about, is whether there is a way to determine how much memory was used/taken up by the objects created in that thread. So yes the memory is taken up overall not just in that thread, but I guess im trying to categorize the memory usage

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) . It
 is a visual tool integrating several commandline JDK tools and lightweight profiling capabilities. Designed for both production and development time use, it further enhances the capability of monitoring and performance analysis for the Java SE platform.

Comment: I've heard of it, but can it be used to get actual values to use to create a bar graph/line chart and be update every couple of seconds?